# Is"How to stop running e4defrag without damage my data?" as unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

[How to stop running e4defrag without damage my data?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472120/how-to-stop-running-e4defrag-without-damage-my-data)
Some people downvote on that question.
I can't find out why unclear.
Can you-all tell me?

Comment: I've edited the question, mostly fixing the language but also adding ever so slightly more info from looking at the tags. I've also nominated it for reopening.

Comment: Thank you, Now I add more specific version information for that question.  @Kusalananda

Answer (score 4):

Well, you've told us absolutely nothing about what you are doing. I suggest you edit your question and add details such as:

- The operating system you are using
- Explain exactly what you're doing. Are you currently running `e4defrag`? What command did you use to launch it?
- What filesystem are you running it on?
- How large is the partition you are running it on?

The more detail you add, the more likely it is that someone will be able to answer.